# Rank Function in SQL 5.6.10

Tags: mysql

I need to apply a Rank function in MYSQL 5.6.10. The issue is, I am getting a syntax error when i am using the standard syntax i found online

Eg:

```
INSERT INTO t(val)
VALUES(1),(2),(2),(3),(4),(4),(5);

SELECT
    val,
    RANK() OVER (
        ORDER BY val
    ) my_rank
FROM
    t;
```

I am getting a red line suggesting a syntax error near 'OVER ('

Comment: correct question to MYsql 5.6 rather then sql 5.6.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know window functions are introduced after version 8 and above.
[source](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-2-introducing-window-functions/)

Something like this may give you some insights.

```
SELECT
    val,
    (select 1+count(*) from t b where t.val>b.val)"rank"
FROM
    t;
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/71f7c4b/1)

Comment: Edited. Check it @Nidutt

Comment: Yes, got it, thanks! Sorry for the late acknowledgement though :)

Comment: Thank you!! and if you do not see much could you als0 upvote please? @Nidutt

Comment: I already tried but i got this- 'Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.'

Comment: If you do not change your mind try again ;) @Nidutt

Answer (score 1):

RANK is only available in MySQL-8.0+